# What is a shading unit and a texture mapping unit in a GPU ? and how does it affect blender?

Tags: materials, hardware

in a graphic card spec like here for example

> The GeForce GTX 970 was a performance graphics card by NVIDIA,
>   launched in September 2014. Built on the 28 nm process, and based on
>   the GM204 graphics processor, in its GM204-200-A1 variant, the card
>   supports DirectX 12.0. The GM204 graphics processor is a large chip
>   with a die area of 398 mm² and 5,200 million transistors. Unlike the
>   fully unlocked GeForce GTX 980, which uses the same GPU but has all
>   **2048 shaders enabled**, NVIDIA has disabled some shading units on the
>   GeForce GTX 970 to reach the product's target shader count. It
>   features **1664 shading units**, **104 texture mapping units** and 56 ROPs.
>   NVIDIA has placed 4,096 MB GDDR5 memory on the card, which are
>   connected using a 256-bit memory interface. The GPU is operating at a
>   frequency of 1050 MHz, which can be boosted up to 1178 MHz, memory is
>   running at 1753 MHz.  Being a dual-slot card, the NVIDIA GeForce GTX
>   970 draws power from 2x 6-pin power connectors, with power draw rated
>   at 148 W maximum. Display outputs include: 1x DVI, 1x HDMI, 3x
>   DisplayPort. GeForce GTX 970 is connected to the rest of the system
>   using a PCI-Express 3.0 x16 interface. The card measures 267 mm in
>   length, and features a dual-slot cooling solution. Its price at launch
>   was 329 US Dollars.

we have some vocabulary:

-**shading unit**

-***shaders***

-***texture mapping units***

### does thoses caracteristics have any impact inside of blender ?

like the limit of material slot we can have?

the limit the number of image texture slot we can have?

the limit the nodes we can have?

for exemple, a scene with 500 material; 3000 image textures, and a material with a node tree of thousands of nodes, is possible with a gpu, or there's some limit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statistics do not impact blender directly. You can have thousands of nodes and shaders and terrabytes of textures if you want and if your PC can handle it.

This is where these components come back into play. The better a GPU is the better it can handle those things. Your GPU can't hold terrabytes of textures, and you're probably going to kill your rendertimes with a nodes setup thousands of nodes deep.

The units mentioned here are directly related to the architecture of the card. A texture mapping unit for example is what's actually doing the caculations for UV unwrapping. Having less of them doesn't change the size of your possible UV map, it just means it takes longer to calculate the unwrapping.

Comment: thansk for the answer!why are old cuda card limited to 88slot of texture then ?

Comment: At some point a card simply can't handle what you're throwing at it any more. 88 textures is incredibly limiting and I can assure you that most video games use more than 88 textures at once. Limits stem from multiple things and can be caused by VRAM or other factors. I can't tell you the specific reason here, sorry for that!